# How to show that intersection of crazy sets is crazy?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We call a set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ to be crazy if for every positive $\delta$ there exists an open set $U$ (with respect to the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb R$) containing $A$ such that the Lebesgue measure of $U\setminus A$ is less than $\delta$.

Given a sequence of crazy sets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\{A_n^c\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is also a sequence of crazy sets, I wish to show that the union and intersection of these sets are also crazy.

Union part is easy: I took the union of the corresponding open sets, that would also be open, and then use union bound to prove the result.

The intersection part I could not do, because intersection of countable number of open sets may not be open. Also, if we also take the union in this case instead of intersection, the measure of the set difference would not be minimized arbitrarily which is what we want.

Suggestions?

Comment: What is $A_n^c$?

Comment: Complement of $A_n$.

Comment: Isn't craziness the same as Lebesgue measurability?

Comment: @1830rbc03, That depends on how you define Lebesgue measurability. We define a set to be Lebesgue measurable if it belongs to the completion of Borel Sigma algebra with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Martund How do you define Lebesgue measure then? Since you say "the Lebesgue measure of $U\setminus A$ is less than $\delta$" I suppose the measure is already given,  although it doesn't really matter if you instead look at the outer measure of $U\setminus A$.

Comment: @1830rbc03, Lebesgue measure is defined to be the unique measure which assigns to every interval $(a,b]$ a measure of $b-a$, extended from the semi ring to the whole Borel sigma algebra using Caratheodory's extension theorem.

Comment: @Martund Well then craziness is obviously the same as Lebesgue measurability. If you require that $U\setminus A$ has measure less than $\delta$ then $U\setminus A$ should be measurable in the first place, so $A$ is also measurable. If you only require that $U\setminus A$ has outer measure less than $\delta$, then for each $n\geq 1$ take a $U_n\supseteq A$ s.t. $U_n\setminus A$ has outer measure less than $1/n$. Then $\left(\bigcap_{n\geq 1}U_n\right)\setminus A$ has outer measure (hence measure) $0$, so again $A$ is measurable.